# How to get finger print name from android device programmatically?

Tags: android, fingerprint, android-fingerprint-api

I am working on one of the application which need finger print name and detail and I am using below code

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
            FingerprintManager fingerprintManager = (FingerprintManager) context.getSystemService(Context.FINGERPRINT_SERVICE);
            if (!fingerprintManager.isHardwareDetected()) {
                // Device doesn't support fingerprint authentication
                System.out.println("CheckLockBroadCastReciever Device doesn't suppor");
            } else if (!fingerprintManager.hasEnrolledFingerprints()) {
                // User hasn't enrolled any fingerprints to authenticate with
                System.out.println("CheckLockBroadCastReciever User hasn't enrolled any fingerprints");
            } else {
                // Everything is ready for fingerprint authentication
                System.out.println("CheckLockBroadCastReciever Everything is ready for fingerprint ");
            }
        }
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for posting your code, but please put a little more description in your question: what problem are you having, what is the result you expect, and [what have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com) so far? Going through the [question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist) will help us better answer your question. Thanks!

Comment: no api to get finger print friendly name in android.

Comment: this will help https://stackoverflow.com/a/53422807/1300894