# Android fingerprint detect new finger added

Tags: android, detect, fingerprint, biometrics

How to detect if the user add new fingerprint to Android settings after he/she authenticate finger inside my application ?

i.e. iOS have something called (evaluatedPolicyDomainState) to detect changes in fingerprint catalog what is the alternative in Android ?

This require for security reasons to prompt password in this case

Comment: It's not possible in Android.

Comment: Thanks hope they support such thing soon

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From the documentation for [`setUserAuthenticationRequired`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/keystore/KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder.html#setUserAuthenticationRequired(boolean)):

> The key will become irreversibly invalidated once the secure lock screen is disabled (reconfigured to None, Swipe or other mode which does not authenticate the user) or when the secure lock screen is forcibly reset (e.g., by a Device Administrator). Additionally, **if the key requires that user authentication takes place for every use of the key, it is also irreversibly invalidated once a new fingerprint is enrolled** or once no more fingerprints are enrolled, unless [`setInvalidatedByBiometricEnrollment(boolean)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/keystore/KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder.html#setInvalidatedByBiometricEnrollment(boolean)) is used to allow validity after enrollment. Attempts to initialize cryptographic operations using such keys will throw KeyPermanentlyInvalidatedException.

So to check if any new fingerprints have been enrolled since you created your fingerprint-associated key, just create a cipher with that key and try to `init` the cipher. If any new fingerprints have been enrolled, the `init` call should trigger a `KeyPermanentlyInvalidatedException`.

Comment: Do you have link for article that describe details of the step

Comment: I don't know of such an article. Just implement fingerprint authentication the way you normally would (I'm sure you can find tutorials for that with google) and make sure to handle all exception that the documentation says might be thrown. The one you're interested in for detecting if additional fingerprints have been enrolled is `KeyPermanentlyInvalidatedException`.

Comment: https://medium.com/@ghodasarabhaumik/android-fingerprint-enrolment-detection-detect-fingerprint-added-removed-68f8189766f9

Comment: THis doens't seem to work from Androd 9 Pie and bellow

Comment: this exception not working on Xiamoi devices... not detecting fingerprint changes. Seems works only if fingerprint-id are sequential

Answer (score 2):

I can get all finger id in integers.

```
private void getFingerprintInfo(Context context) 
{
    try {
        FingerprintManager fingerprintManager = (FingerprintManager) context.getSystemService(Context.FINGERPRINT_SERVICE);
        Method method = FingerprintManager.class.getDeclaredMethod("getEnrolledFingerprints");
        Object obj = method.invoke(fingerprintManager);

        if (obj != null) {
            Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("android.hardware.fingerprint.Fingerprint");
            Method getFingerId = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("getFingerId");

            for (int i = 0; i < ((List) obj).size(); i++)
            {
                Object item = ((List) obj).get(i);
                if(item != null)
                {
                    System.out.println("fkie4. fingerId: " + getFingerId.invoke(item));
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException | IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

please refer to this: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/hardware/fingerprint/Fingerprint.java

there is a public method getFingerId( ), but it is not available for us to call because it has "@UnsupportedAppUsage".

so you need to use reflection to call the method. after you get a list of fingerprint id, you can encrypt them and store in sharedPreference.

Finger id is the id of the fingerprints stored in setting

After you get all finger ids, you can determine if user has added/deleted a fingerprint.

No need to count on the KeyPermanentlyInvalidatedException. It is not thrown in Android 8.0

Good luck!!!...

don't believe google did such a poor job

Comment: I've tested it and it seems a nice approach so far but one using it should be aware about two things: (1) the sequential id generated by some vendors (check [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/65578763#comment26) for more info) and, in addition to that, (2) the fact that `getEnrolledFingerprints` has sadly been greylisted (check [here](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/restrictions-non-sdk-interfaces) for info), which means this won't work if your app targets API 29+.

Comment: I want to add on what said gbazilio that `getFingerId()` not return a valid fingerId on Samsung devices, it return an index (1, 2, 3, ...) that can not be useful to check if a new fingerprint is added. <br/> Also there are 4 other function that i tested but not very usefull like : `getName()` , `getGroupId()` , `getDeviceId()` and `describeContents()`.<br/> The `getName()`may can be usefull if it is concatenated with index but the problem here is when you delete the last fingerprint saved and create other with the same name

Comment: It seems the variable is modified in provided class. And can not be used anymore. :(

Answer (score 0):

```
    private String getFingerprintInfo(Context context) throws NoSuchMethodException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException, ClassNotFoundException {
        FingerprintManager fingerprintManager = (FingerprintManager) context.getSystemService(Context.FINGERPRINT_SERVICE);
        Method method = FingerprintManager.class.getDeclaredMethod("getEnrolledFingerprints");
        Object obj = method.invoke(fingerprintManager);
        String allFingerPrintInfo = "";
        if (obj != null) {
            Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("android.hardware.fingerprint.Fingerprint");
            for (int i = 0; i < ((List) obj).size(); i++) {
                Object fingerPrint = ((List) obj).get(i);
                if (fingerPrint != null) {
                    String fingerPrintInfo = "";
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
                        Parcel p = Parcel.obtain();
                        p.setDataPosition(0);
//                        Method writeToParcel = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("writeToParcel", Parcel.class, Integer.class);
                        clazz.getDeclaredMethods()[1].invoke(fingerPrint, p, 0);
                        p.setDataPosition(0);
                        fingerPrintInfo = p.readString() + "_" + p.readInt() + "_" + p.readLong();
                    } else {
                        Method getFingerId = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("getFingerId");
                        fingerPrintInfo = (String) getFingerId.invoke(fingerPrint);
                    }
                    allFingerPrintInfo += fingerPrintInfo + "*";
                }
            }

        }

        return allFingerPrintInfo;

    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
/**
 * Generate NIST P-256 EC Key pair for signing and verification
 *
 * @param keyName
 * @param invalidatedByBiometricEnrollment
 * @return
 * @throws Exception
 */
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.P)
private KeyPair generateKeyPair(String keyName, boolean invalidatedByBiometricEnrollment) throws Exception {
  KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_EC, "AndroidKeyStore");
  KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder builder = new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(keyName,
      KeyProperties.PURPOSE_SIGN)
      .setAlgorithmParameterSpec(new ECGenParameterSpec("secp256r1"))
      .setDigests(KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA256,
          KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA384,
          KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA512)
      // Require the user to authenticate with a biometric to authorize every use of the key
      .setUserAuthenticationRequired(true)
      .setInvalidatedByBiometricEnrollment(invalidatedByBiometricEnrollment);
  keyPairGenerator.initialize(builder.build());
  return keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
}
```

Answer (score -4):

You can't add new fingerprints from your app.

Inside your application you only have access to the Auth Fingerprint Method which checks against registered fingerprints through the keyStore.

Comment: Needs more elaboration on how we can detect new fingerprint registration.