# How to detect the removal fingerprint in Android?

Tags: android, fingerprint, android-fingerprint-api

I am currently doing research on Android fingerprint API.

As I have cloned the fingerprint sample, 'FingerprintDialog' https://github.com/googlesamples/android-FingerprintDialog

There is a mechanism for checking if new fingerprint is added to the device and ask for password instead of fingerprint once after the addition of new fingerprint.

However, I cannot find any material online about detecting the removal of fingerprint in the App. As the result, I would like to know if there is any method that I can detect the removal of fingerprint in my App.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44515668/android-fingerprint-detect-new-finger-added

Comment: Thanks, but sadly the reference you provide is about detecting a fingerprint enrollment instead of a removal of a single fingerprint, which I can successfully achieve in my program. Thanks anyway.