# KeyPermanentlyInvalidatedException is not working

Tags: android, private-key, android-fingerprint-api

I used KeyPermanentlyInvalidatedException to detect a new fingerprint is added. But it doesn't throw KeyPermanentlyInvalidatedException.

I tried these step:

1. List item
2. Create key pair
3. Init Signature from private key
4. Add new fingerprint from phone's Setting
5. Try Init Signature from private key again
   But it doesn't throw KeyPermanentlyInvalidatedException

I also found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44515668/android-fingerprint-detect-new-finger-added?noredirect=1&lq=1) from stackoverflow but it didn't help me.

From document:

> The key will become irreversibly invalidated once the secure lock screen is disabled (reconfigured to None, Swipe or other mode which does not authenticate the user) or when the secure lock screen is forcibly reset (e.g., by a Device Administrator). Additionally, if the key requires that user authentication takes place for every use of the key, it is also irreversibly invalidated once a new fingerprint is enrolled or once no more fingerprints are enrolled, unless setInvalidatedByBiometricEnrollment(boolean) is used to allow validity after enrollment. Attempts to initialize cryptographic operations using such keys will throw KeyPermanentlyInvalidatedException.

Here is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_authenticate);

    mButtonTest = findViewById(R.id.button_test);
    mButtonTest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            buttonTestOnClick();
        }
    });

    boolean isFirstTime = PreferenceManager.getInstances().getFirstTime();
    PreferenceManager.getInstances().setFirstTime(false);

    if (isFirstTime) {
        createKeyPair();
    }
}

private void buttonTestOnClick() {
    boolean result = initSignature();
    Log.e("iii", "Create signature result: " + result);

    boolean isFirstTime = PreferenceManager.getInstances().getFirstTime();

    if (result) {
        if (isFirstTime) {
            enroll();
        }
        startListening();
    }
}


/**
 * Generates an asymmetric key pair in the Android Keystore. Every use of the private key must
 * be authorized by the user authenticating with fingerprint. Public key use is unrestricted.
 */
public void createKeyPair() {
    try {
        mKeyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_EC, "AndroidKeyStore");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchProviderException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to get an instance of KeyPairGenerator", e);
    }

    // The enrolling flow for fingerprint. This is where you ask the user to set up fingerprint
    // for your flow. Use of keys is necessary if you need to know if the set of
    // enrolled fingerprints has changed.
    try {
        // Set the alias of the entry in Android KeyStore where the key will appear
        // and the constrains (purposes) in the constructor of the Builder
        mKeyPairGenerator.initialize(
                new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(KEY_NAME,
                        KeyProperties.PURPOSE_SIGN)
                        .setDigests(KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA256)
                        .setAlgorithmParameterSpec(new ECGenParameterSpec("secp256r1"))
                        // Require the user to authenticate with a fingerprint to authorize
                        // every use of the private key
                        .setUserAuthenticationRequired(true)
                        .build());
        mKeyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
    } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}


/**
 * Initialize the {@link Signature} instance with the created key in the
 * {@link #createKeyPair()} method.
 *
 * @return {@code true} if initialization is successful, {@code false} if the lock screen has
 * been disabled or reset after the key was generated, or if a fingerprint got enrolled after
 * the key was generated.
 */
private boolean initSignature() {
    // Create keystore
    try {
        mKeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
    } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to get an instance of KeyStore", e);
    }

    // Create signature
    try {
        mSignature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withECDSA");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to get an instance of Signature", e);
    }


    try {
        mKeyStore.load(null);
        PrivateKey key = (PrivateKey) mKeyStore.getKey(KEY_NAME, null);
        mSignature.initSign(key);
        return true;
    } catch (KeyPermanentlyInvalidatedException e) {
        return false;
    } catch (KeyStoreException | CertificateException | UnrecoverableKeyException | IOException
            | NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeyException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to init Cipher", e);
    }
}


private void enroll() {
    try {
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
        keyStore.load(null);
        PublicKey publicKey = keyStore.getCertificate(AuthenticateActivity.KEY_NAME).getPublicKey();
        // Provide the public key to the backend. In most cases, the key needs to be transmitted
        // to the backend over the network, for which Key.getEncoded provides a suitable wire
        // format (X.509 DER-encoded). The backend can then create a PublicKey instance from the
        // X.509 encoded form using KeyFactory.generatePublic. This conversion is also currently
        // needed on API Level 23 (Android M) due to a platform bug which prevents the use of
        // Android Keystore public keys when their private keys require user authentication.
        // This conversion creates a new public key which is not backed by Android Keystore and
        // thus is not affected by the bug.
        KeyFactory factory = KeyFactory.getInstance(publicKey.getAlgorithm());
        X509EncodedKeySpec spec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(publicKey.getEncoded());
        PublicKey verificationKey = factory.generatePublic(spec);
        //mStoreBackend.enroll("user", "password", verificationKey);
    } catch (KeyStoreException | CertificateException | NoSuchAlgorithmException |
            IOException | InvalidKeySpecException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But **initSignature()** function allways returns true.

Comment: Which device and Android version? I've seen a similar problem on the Nexus 5X, but that was when removing all enrolled fingerprints.

Comment: I use Asus Zenfone 3 Max

Comment: i have the same problem. The documentation is wrong or the implementation has some small unknown details

Comment: Same problem here, Nexus 6 Plus (SDK 26). Have you found any solution?

Comment: Any solution you find for this?

Comment: Has anyone resolved this issue yet?